# Foreign Key IntegrityError at /new_project null value in column "project_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I know this is probably a duplicate but I've tried every solution on other problems of this nature and I can't seem to solve this, here's my issue.

**Models**

```
class Project(models.Model):
     project_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     project_url = models.URLField()
     last_update = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.project_name

class Commit(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name="project")
    commit_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    commit_msg = models.TextField()
    commit_info = models.TextField()
    regex_tags = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.commit_id + " - " + self.author + " - "
```

I have these models and I need every commit to be associated with the project they come from. In my view, I do this:

```
class new_project_view(View):
     def get(self, request):
         return render(request, 'new_project.html')

     def post(self,request):
         if 'create_project' in request.POST:
             project_name = request.POST['projectname']
             project_url = request.POST['projecturl']
             print("project url ", project_url)
             print("project name", project_name)
             generate_log_file(project_url)
             logfile = open("logfile.txt", "r")
              if not logfile.readlines() :
                  print("Estou vazio")
                  logfile.close()
                  return render(request, 'new_project.html')
             else:
                 print("Add log to DB")
                 logfile.close()

                 #Here I create the project model and send it to a function
            #that adds to the commits.

                 project = Project.objects.create()
                 project.project_name = project_name
                 project.project_url = project_url
                 project.save()
                 add_log_to_db(project)
                 print("Added")
      return render(request, 'new_project.html')
```

The add_log_to_db function does a lot but it's working as intended as I was able to create the commits and populate the DB before I wanted to have a project associated with it. So I'll share the snippet where I try to add the project to the Commit model.

```
elif check_flag==1:
        if lines== '\n':
            regex_str = ''
            print("---")
            print(project.project_name)
            print(project.project_url)
            print(project.last_update)
            print(project.pk)
            print("---")
            commit_details = Commit.objects.create()
            commit_details.project = project
            commit_details.commit_id = commit_id
            commit_details.author = author
            commit_details.commit_msg = str_commit
            commit_details.commit_info = str_mod
            commit_details.date = date_obj

            for i in range(len(regex_list)):
                if(i != len(regex_list)):
                    regex_str+= regex_list[i]+","
                else:
                    regex_str+=regex_list[i]
            
            commit_details.regex_tags = regex_str
            commit_details.save()
```

The project prints fine so I have no idea why this error. I've dropped everything and created a new database numerous times. Anyone has any idea on this?
Thank you in advance.

I'll leave the traceback as well in case it's useful, thanks!

```
    Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/new_project

Django Version: 3.2.4
Python Version: 3.8.6
Installed Applications:
['app',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dingo/Desktop/Project Scanner/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (null value in column "project_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, , , 2021-06-17 15:50:09.841386+00, , , null, null).
) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/home/dingo/Desktop/Project Scanner/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/dingo/Desktop/Project Scanner/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/dingo/Desktop/Project Scanner/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dingo/Desktop/Project Scanner/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dingo/Desktop/Project Scanner/Project-Scanner/ProjectScanner/app/views.py", line 48, in post
    add_log_to_db(project)
  File "/home/dingo/Desktop/Project Scanner/Project-Scanner/ProjectScanner/app/aux.py", line 40, in add_log_to_db
    commit_details = Commit.objects.create()
  File "/home/dingo/Desktop/Project Scanner/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dingo/Desktop/Project Scanner/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 453, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/dingo/Desktop/Project Scanner/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/home/dingo/Desktop/Project Scanner/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 763, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/home/dingo/Desktop/Project Scanner/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 868, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/home/dingo/Desktop/Project Scanner/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 906, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/home/dingo/Desktop/Project Scanner/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dingo/Desktop/Project Scanner/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1270, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/home/dingo/Desktop/Project Scanner/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1416, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/dingo/Desktop/Project Scanner/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/dingo/Desktop/Project Scanner/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/dingo/Desktop/Project Scanner/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/dingo/Desktop/Project Scanner/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/dingo/Desktop/Project Scanner/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/dingo/Desktop/Project Scanner/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /new_project
Exception Value: null value in column "project_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, , , 2021-06-17 15:50:09.841386+00, , , null, null).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
commit_details = Commit()
```

Your Construction is wrong, create() saves to the database

Comment: Oh god I can't believe it was that. Thank you so much!